# get only one field value from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const subjects = [
  {
    id:1,
    class:"class 5",
    sub:"social"
  },
  {
    id:2,
    class:"class 6",
    sub:"English"
  },
  {
    id:3,
    class:"class 5",
    sub:"Physics"
  }
]

const students = [
  {
    id:1,
    name:"john",
    attendedSubject:[1]
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name:"james",
    attendedSubject:[1,2]
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name:"jack",
    attendedSubject:[2]
  },
]
```

How to get all the students where class === class 5 and attendedSubject sub id's ie i am having a radio button where user will selects class (class 5 for example) and a drop down where all sub will be displayed in the dropdown where class === class 5 and based on the class and sub how to get sudents with class 5 and particular subject ex: selected class is class 5 and selectedsub is physics the output obj should be c

```
const result = [{
  id:1,
  name:"john",
  attendedSubject:[1]
},
{
  id:2,
  name:"james",
  attendedSubject:[1,2]
}]
```

Comment: how do you get the above mentioned result from `'class 5'` and `'physics'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to have 2 loops.

1. Find a class based on X, Y and Z
2. Find students based on subject X.

```js
const queryClass = subjects.find(s => s.class === 'class 6' && s.sub === 'English')
const output = students.filter(s => s.attendedSubject.includes(queryClass.id))
console.log(output)
```

outputs:

```js
[
  { id: 2, name: 'james', attendedSubject: [ 1, 2 ] },
  { id: 3, name: 'jack', attendedSubject: [ 2 ] }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Is there any way to get like now if i const result = subjects.find(s => s.class ==="class 5") i will get whole object where class===class 5  but is there any way to get the result like [{sub:"social"},{sub:"Physics"}] please help with this also

Comment: @SaiCharan for that, you'd need to re-map the object. You could either add additional `.map()` loop, or replace either of the above with `.reduce()` and make sure to filter out what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work

```
let filteredSub=subjects.filter(subject=>{
  return subject.class==='class 5'
})
let filteredStudents=students.filter(student=>{
      return filteredSub.some(subject=>{
            return student.attendedSubject.indexOf(subject.id)>-1
      })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer can you please tell me how to get result of filteredSub  with only sub like [{sub:"social"},{sub:"Physics"}]

Comment: it's simple you can write new condition just for example you simply use function `chaining subjects.filter(subject=>{
  return subject.class==='class 5'
}).map(item=>({"sub":item.sub}))` but it will destroy the above solution as it is base on filtered subject id